# Django ORM values() and select_related() raise TypeError

Tags: python, django, orm

In my django project i have to do an ORM query like this:

```
ordered = t_threads.objects.values('thread_stag').filter(thread_status='DEAD',id_test__test_main__descr__contains= 'Hello').distinct().select_related().order_by('id')[1:10]
```

i need to group result for value 'thread_stag' filtered for status and test description, having all values from related tables, but when i execute the above query system return:

> raise TypeError("Cannot call select_related() after .values() or .values_lis
>   t()")

if i remove the "select_related()" option i don't have values from related tables.
How can i achieve my result in django ORM?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: try
`ordered = t_threads.objects.filter(thread_status='DEAD',id_test__test_main__descr__contains= 'Hello').values('thread_stag').order_by('id').distinct()[1:10]`

Comment: try move values('thread_stag') in last

Comment: `select_related` does *not* change the fields you get back, it just makes following related objects more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Just move `values` to the end like below:

```
ordered = t_threads.objects \ 
           .filter(thread_status='DEAD',id_test__test_main__descr__contains= 'Hello') \
           .distinct() \ 
           .select_related() \ 
           .values('thread_stag') \ 
           .order_by('id')[1:10]
```

Notice then you also have to specify a fields list for `select_related`!